# Socket recv vs readline performs very differently on Windows and Linux, why?

Tags: python, linux, windows, sockets

I have been looking at fixing an issue with some socket code. I'm receiving data from a server in the form of jsonlines (json objects separated by \r\n). The original code only checks if each .recv call returns bytes ending with \r\n and doesn't handle the case where many messages may be present.

I switched out the original code for a `socket.makefile()` and `.readline()` which fixes the issue. On Windows the new code is much, much faster. But on Linux the difference is very small, perhaps even no different within an error margin.

Am I missing something here? Why is the exact same code much faster on Windows and barely noticeably faster on Linux? I suspect it is an issue with my benchmark.

My benchmark:

```
import datetime
import json
import socket
import threading
import time
import timeit

from typing import Optional

BUFFER_SIZE = 1024
N_BATCHES_OF_DATA = 100
PORT = 5678

def server(n_batches_of_data, port):
    data = [
        json.dumps({"a": "b"}).encode('utf-8') + b'\r\n',
        json.dumps({"c": "d", "e": "f"}).encode('utf-8') + b'\r\n',
        json.dumps({"g" * (512-5): "h" * (512-5)}).encode('utf-8') + b'\r\n',  # 1022 bytes, with linefeed == 1024, exact size of buffer
        json.dumps({"i" * (512-4): "j" * (512-4)}).encode('utf-8') + b'\r\n',  # 1024 bytes, with linefeed == 1026 - exceeds buffer, just
        json.dumps({"k" * (256-5): "l" * (256-5)}).encode('utf-8') + b'\r\n',  # 510 bytes, with linefeed == 512, half of buffer
        json.dumps({"m" * (256-5): "n" * (256-5)}).encode('utf-8') + b'\r\n',  # 510 bytes, with linefeed == 512, half of buffer
        json.dumps({"o" * (1024-5): "p" * (1024-5)}).encode('utf-8') + b'\r\n',  # 2046 bytes, with linefeed == 2048, 2x size of buffer
        json.dumps({"q" * 100: "r" * 100})[0:25].encode('utf-8'),  # part 1
        json.dumps({"q" * 100: "r" * 100})[25:50].encode('utf-8'),  # part 2
        json.dumps({"q" * 100: "r" * 100})[50:75].encode('utf-8'),  # part 3
        json.dumps({"q" * 100: "r" * 100})[50:75].encode('utf-8'),  # part 4
        json.dumps({"q" * 100: "r" * 100})[75:].encode('utf-8') + b'\r\n',  # part 5
        json.dumps({"s": "t"}).encode('utf-8') + b'\r\n' + json.dumps({"u": "v"}).encode('utf-8') + b'\r\n' + json.dumps({"w": "x"}).encode('utf-8') + b'\r\n'+ json.dumps({"y": "z"}).encode('utf-8') + b'\r\n',  # several small messages
    ] * n_batches_of_data

    server_socket = socket.socket()
    server_socket.bind(("localhost", port))
    server_socket.listen(2)
    while True:
        conn, address = server_socket.accept()  # accept new connection
        for d in data:
            conn.sendall(d)
        conn.close()

def read_using_recv(buffer_size, port):
  s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
  s.settimeout(10)
  s.connect(("localhost", port))

  # this code has a bug where messages can get stuck in data if part doesn't end with \r\n
  (data, part) = ("", "")
  while True:
      try:
          part = s.recv(buffer_size)
      except (socket.timeout, socket.error) as e:
            return

      # an empty string indicates the server shutdown the socket
      if len(part) == 0:
          return

      data += part.decode('utf8')

      if data.endswith('\r\n'):
        data.split('\r\n')
        data = ''

def read_using_readline(buffer_size, port):
  s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
  s.settimeout(10)
  s.connect(("localhost", port))
  f = s.makefile('r', buffering=buffer_size, newline='\r\n', encoding='utf8')
  while True:
      try:
          part = f.readline()
      except (socket.timeout, socket.error) as e:
            return

      # an empty string indicates the server shutdown the socket
      if len(part) == 0:
          return

if __name__ == '__main__':
  t = threading.Thread(target=server, args=[N_BATCHES_OF_DATA, PORT], daemon=True)
  t.start()

  time.sleep(5)

  print('read_using_recv', timeit.timeit((lambda: read_using_recv(BUFFER_SIZE, PORT)), number=5000))
  print('read_using_readline', timeit.timeit((lambda: read_using_readline(BUFFER_SIZE, PORT)), number=5000))
```

Results on Windows:

```
read_using_recv: 134.77089489999344
read_using_readline: 78.2258090999967
```

Results on Linux:

```
read_using_recv 22.800755036994815
read_using_readline 20.403162219095975
```

Comment: 10ms is a ridiculously short read timeout. Use something practical like ten *seconds*. Also you are conflating timeouts with connection closures. They aren't the same thing.

Comment: settimeout accepts seconds, not milliseconds. Also this is just a benchmark and not production code.